# Safari/Opera/Chrome/FF pull different Stylesheets from the exact same file location

Tags: css, safari, opera

I am running a Wordpress build on a web host. The most up to date stylesheet, titled style.css is placed where it needs to be in the child theme folder, under wp-content/themes/geisinger/style.css.

Chrome and Firefox are displaying the updated content relative to the updated CSS file. Safari and Opera are not.

The website in question is my client's: [kurt4apa.org/campaign](http://kurt4apa.org/campaign)

I have used the Browser web consoles to inspect what file is being pulled. Chrome and Firefox showcase that the most up to date CSS files are there and being put into effect but Safari/Opera are showing stylesheets from earlier in the day. I want to emphasize that so far as I can tell, the style.css file is in the exact **same** location; the four browsers are pulling the **same** file but only the former two are are using the updated version.

I've tried clearing the browsers' caches and cookies. Beyond this, I am entirely lost to the solution. All help is appreciated; thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's a weird server side caching problem, to test it try changing the numbers at the end of the html code from 'http://www.kurt4apa.org/campaign/wp-content/themes/geisinger/style.css?ver=**3.5.1**' to 'http://www.kurt4apa.org/campaign/wp-content/themes/geisinger/style.css?ver=**3.5.2**'

Comment: It worked! Coincidnetally, the problem has resolved itself without edits on Safari but Opera still has yet to update. Any solution on how to reset the server cache for future reference?

Comment: I'm not sure, there are many things that can lead to this problem, but you can read the codex for some solutions:  http://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens . If that doesn't help you can use something like http://jasongraphix.com/journal/css-cachebuster/